# How to perform PCA analysis on space-time data for few species in R?

Tags: pca, spatial, spatio-temporal, pcoa, hellinger

The data-set I'm looking to analyze has 6 sites. Each site was sampled at five unique locations each month for a year. We could identify abundance of 4 species across the data set. Together, I have 360 points in space-time of 4 species. I also have few environmental variables. My data-set looks something like this.

```
Month    Site    Plot  Temp   Humidity  pH   SP1  SP2  SP3  SP4
Jan       1       1     15      20       4     1   2    3    4
Jan       1       2     15      21       4     2   3    4    5
..
Dec       6       5     2        3       5      0   0    0    1
```

I want to do a PCA analysis to identify how species partition their environment. But I don't know if these are too few species to do such an analysis. Also, most PCA analysis I see are done in space, but not space and time. How do I incorporate both space and time? Do I simply treat the sites at different points as different spatial points? I would appreciate any help and guidance as I am quite new to this.